# Manipulate a Plot that contains a variable that contains symbol

Tags: plotting, manipulate, evaluation, symbols

This snippet

```
mm = m
Manipulate[{mm, Plot[mm x, {x, 0, 1}]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

(`m` is not defined anywhere) produces a sadly fixed output, `m` remains symbolic.

This instead

```
mm = m
Manipulate[Evaluate@{mm, Plot[mm x, {x, 0, 1}]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

makes the first element of the list be dynamically evaluated, but not the `Plot`, which remains empty because `m` remains symbolic. Lastly,

```
mm = m
Manipulate[{%, Plot[% x, {x, 0, 1}]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

gets the correct thing, everything is evaluated dynamically. Why?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it... `Manipulate`-able variables are only evaluated when they are defined within `Manipulate`

```
mm = m
Manipulate[{%, Plot[% x, {x, 0, 1}]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

is the same as writing,

```
Manipulate[{mm = m, Plot[mm x, {x, 0, 1}]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

In your first two examples the variable `m` is undefined and remains that way (i.e. is not linked to the `Manipulate` variable `m`).

Is this an answer? Perhaps, not quite?...

It is interesting that `Evaluate` seems to force `mm` to link to the `Manipulate`-"`m`" but doesn't work for `Plot`... Also, if only `Plot` is evaluated, e.g.,

```
Manipulate[{mm, Evaluate[Plot[mm x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {m, 0, 1}]
```

The output slider stops working, however, the graphic is now dynamically linked to the other sliders/outputs in the notebook... try it!

Weird.