# Simple problem with Manipulate and Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, replacement

Would anyone have an idea why the following doesn't work:

```
rule = {z -> x^2 + 2 x + y};
Manipulate[
 Plot[z /. rule, {x, 0, 10}],
 {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}
 ]
```

But the following do:

```
rule = {z -> x^2 + 2 x + y};
z /. rule;
Manipulate[
 Plot[%, {x, 0, 10}],
 {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}
 ]
```

and:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[z /. z -> x^2 + 2 x + y, {x, 0, 10}],
 {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}
 ]
```

I was looking to `Plot` and `Manipulate` the results from a `Solve` of multiple equations, but it seems like I haven't understood the substitution rules correctly.

Thanks,

Jaleno

Comment: This is explained in the **Possible Issues** of the document of `Manipulate`: Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters. You can check the document for more information: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.en.html

Comment: The new thing for me in this question is why `%` is evaluated.  E.g., this works with `%` in place of `rule`: `rule = {z -> x^2 + 2 x + y}; Manipulate[Plot[z /. %, {x, 0, 10}], {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}]`.  I thought `Out[1]` would be treated like the global variable but it's not.

Comment: @MichaelE2, it looks like `Manipulate` has special handling of `Out` via ``Manipulate`Dump`resolveOut[]``

Comment: @SimonWoods It clearly does: see ``?Manipulate`Dump`resolveOut``  Good find!  Consider putting it in an answer.

Comment: probable duplicate with no upvoted answer : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/manipulate-a-plot-that-contains-a-variable-that-contains-symbol

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The general issue, as mentioned by xzczd, is that `Manipulate` only "notices" explicit visible parameters. This is because when you evaluate something like `Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}]` and start waggling the slider, you are not changing the value of the *global* symbol `x`, but instead a temporary symbol called something like `x$$15`. You can see this like so:

```
Manipulate[{SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ x, x}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

So in order to make the magic happen, `Manipulate` has to find occurrences of `x` in the manipulated expression and replace them with the temporary symbol. It does this *before* evaluating the expression.

So if you try this...

```
a = 10 + x;
Manipulate[a, {x, 0, 1}]
```

...`Manipulate` looks at the unevaluated expression `a` and finds no occurrence of `x`. So you get this output:

[image]

Here `a` is evaluating to `10 + x` (that's the global symbol `x`) but the slider is controlling some temporary symbol like `x$$15`.

To get the desired behaviour you can use `With` to replace the `a` inside the `Manipulate` with its evaluated form `10 + x`. That way `Manipulate` will "notice" the `x` and replace it with the temporary symbol tied to the slider:

```
With[{a = a}, Manipulate[a, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

So for the problem in the question, the plot can be obtained like this:

```
rule = {z -> x^2 + 2 x + y};
With[{rule = rule},
 Manipulate[Plot[z /. rule, {x, 0, 10}], {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

**Special behaviour with `Out`**

The apparent mystery is why this works:

```
a = 10 + x;
Manipulate[%, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The answer is simply that `Manipulate` has special handling for `Out`. Any occurrence of `Out` in the manipulated expression is evaluated before `Manipulate` does its localization, similarly to what we did above with `With`. So `Manipulate` "notices" the `x` and works as desired.

For those who like to know these things: the handling of `Out` is implemented by `` Manipulate`Dump`resolveOut `` using the Trott-Strzebonski trick.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, this is a great insight into the workings of Manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another quick way to make your initial example work:

```
rule = {z -> x^2 + 2 x + y};
Manipulate[Plot[#, {x, 0, 10}], {{y, 2, "y"}, 1, 5}] &@z /. rule
```