# Manipulate a Show

Tags: manipulate

It takes me a long time to construct the following picture:

```
σ = 2;
A = 1;
δ = 0.03;
pa = Plot[
      Max[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))], 
      {β, 0, 4}, Filling -> {1 -> Top}, 
      FillingStyle -> LightBlue, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
      AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}
     ];

pb = Plot[
      Min[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β)A - δ))], {β, 0, 4}, 
      Filling -> {1 -> Axis, LightBlue}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
      AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, FillingStyle -> LightRed, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}
     ];

pc = Plot[
      {(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))}, {β, 0, 4}, 
      Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {LightOrange, LightGreen}}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}
     ];

Show[
  pa, pb, pc, 
  ImageSize -> Scaled[.5], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}
]
```

which gives exactly what I want. Now I would like to `Manipulate` this picture on $A$, $\delta$ and $\sigma$. But when I create the command

```
Manipulate[
  Show[{pa, pb, pc}], 
  {σ, 0.1, 2}, {A, 0.1, 5}, {δ, 0.001, 1}, 
  ContentSize -> Large
]
```

I have the graphic, the `Manipulate` container but nothing append when I move the cursor.

Incidentally I would like to label the curves: I know there are some exchanges on the subject, but it is not clear if the solutions will work with `Manipulate`.

Comment: Cyrille, `Manipulate` needs to "see" the parameters in the definition of your plots *explicitly* in order to be able to change them; that's why moving the definitions of the plots inside the `Manipulate` works, as suggested by JasonB below. See also the docs of Manipulate, in the "Possible Issues" section: "Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulate using a variable defined outside of the manipulate function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31322/manipulate-using-a-variable-defined-outside-of-the-manipulate-function). Also see [How are parameters evaluated for a plot in manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate).

Answer (score 3):

Move all of your plot definitions inside the `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 pa = Plot[
   Max[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/\
σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))], {β, 0, 4}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> Top}, FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}];
 pb = Plot[
   Min[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/\
σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))], {β, 0, 4}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> Axis, LightBlue}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
   AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, FillingStyle -> LightRed, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}];
 pc = Plot[{(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) \
(1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))}, {β, 0, 4}, 
   Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {LightOrange, LightGreen}}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}];

 Show[{pa, pb, pc}], {σ, 0.1, 2}, {A, 0.1, 5}, {δ, 
  0.001, 1}, ContentSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: ... or alternatively define those plots as explicit functions of the parameters, so `Manipulate` is aware of the explicit dependence on those parameters. This may work to reduce clutter within the manipulate and retain the external definitions. Anyway, the issue has been discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate) as well, so I would think this is a possible duplicate.

Comment: @MarcoB You are totally right.... I get sloppy when questions come in right before I leave work, just post the first thing that works. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `DyanmicModule` to give better localization. I would also put as many plotting options as possible into `Show` to reduce code repetition.

```
DynamicModule[{pa, pb, pc, A, δ, σ},
  pa[A_, δ_, σ_] := 
    Plot[Max[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))], {β, 0, 4},
      Filling -> {1 -> Top},
      FillingStyle -> LightBlue];
  pb[A_, δ_, σ_] := 
    Plot[Min[(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))], {β, 0, 4},
      PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}},
      Filling -> {1 -> Bottom},
      FillingStyle -> LightRed];
  pc[A_, δ_, σ_] := 
    Plot[{(1 + β)/(2 β), (1 + β)^2/(2 β) (1/σ (β/(1 + β) A - δ))}, {β, 0, 4},
      Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {LightOrange, LightGreen}}}];
  Manipulate[
    Show[pb[A, δ, σ], pa[A, δ, σ], pc[A, δ, σ],
      AxesLabel -> {"β", "ξ"},
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
    {σ, 0.1, 2., 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {A, 0.1, 5., 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {δ, 0.01, 1.0, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    ContentSize -> Large]]
```

[image: demo]

Note that `pb` must be plotted first because it is controlling the plot range.

Answer (score 1):

Define plotting functions outside Manipulate:

```
g1[k_] := Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
g2[k_] := Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
g3[k_] := Show[g1[k], g2[k]];
Manipulate[g3[k], {k, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: Although I think I can see where you are going with this, I am not sure that it is clearly spelled out. Your suggestion is to define the plots as functions explicitly dependent on the parameters to be manipulated to circumvent scoping issues, correct? Since the OP showed full code for her problem, perhaps you could show the pertinent solution here, rather than a generic one.

Comment: How can I copy, from Mathematica, and paste, here, code containing greek characters ?

Comment: I copy straight from Mathematica, then use this character converter: http://steampiano.net/msc/ . mgoldberg also has some [general pointers on copy / pasting formatted code for this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site).