# Manipulating PlotRange in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

why does the following code not work?

```
r = {2.30 Cos[5s], -2.30 Sin[5s]};

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t], Cos[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {{-r[[1]] , r[[1]]}, {-r[[2]] , r[[2]]}}], {s, 0.1, 2 Pi, 0.01}]
```

but if I put r[[1]] and r[[2]] by hand it works

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t], Cos[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2.3 Cos[5 s],2.3 Cos[5 s]}, {2.3 Sin[5 s] , -2.3 Sin[5 s]}}]
,{s, 0.1, 2 Pi,0.01}]
```

Comment: It does not work because `Manipulate` does not "see" that $r$ depends on $s$, the manipulated variable. The quickest fix would be to move the definition of `r` to inside the `Manipulate`, rather than outside it: `Manipulate[r = ..; ParametricPlot[..], {s, 0.1, 2 Pi, 0.01}]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate). See also [Manipulate Plot Sliders Not Working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119089/27951) and [Manipulate using a variable defined outside of the manipulate function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31322/27951).

Comment: Finally, your PlotRange definition could be represented more briefly using `PlotRange -> ({-#, #} & /@ r)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f[s_] := {2.30 Cos[5 s], -2.30 Sin[5 s]};
Manipulate[
ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t], Cos[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {{-f[s][[1]], f[s][[1]]}, {-f[s][[2]], f[s][[2]]}}],
{s, 0.1, 2 Pi, 0.01}
]
```