# When using PopupMenu other controls stop working

Tags: plotting, manipulate, gui-construction

I have an interactive plot in a `Manipulate` expression with a `PopupMenu`. I want to be able to select the function being plotted with the popup. When I use the PopupMenu the other controls (sliders) stop working. I am unable to find the problem.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], 
  {f, {a # + b & -> "Linear", Abs [a # + b] & -> "Absolute Value"}, 
    ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
  {a, -3, 3, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, -5, "y-intercept"}, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I have seen several examples for `PopupMenu` and `SetterBar`. But none where parameters in a dynamically selected function can be changed by other controls.

Comment: Moving your rules to the `Plot` command does what I think you want. `Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x] /. {a -> $a, b -> $b}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], {f, {a # + b & -> "Linear", 
   Abs[a # + b] & -> "Absolute Value"}, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {$a, -3, 3, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{$b, -5, "y-intercept"}, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Another possibility is `Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], {f, {a # + b & -> "Linear", 
   Abs[a # + b] & -> "Absolute Value"}, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {a, -3, 3, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, -5, "y-intercept"}, -5, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`.  The plot needs to be dynamic in order to be updated in this fashion.  If I come up with a good explanation *why*, I'll post an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: ...and it looks like this issue has been [addressed previously](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25131/7167).  It seems to deal with the visibility of symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much...the following worked with no $ on the slider. Manipulate[ Plot[f[x] /. {a -> $a, b -> $b}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], {f, {a # + b & -> "Linear", Abs[a # + b] & -> "Absolute Value"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {a, -3, 3, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, -5, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few small mistakes which are easily fixed.

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @ Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}], 
  {{f, a # + b &}, {a # + b & -> "Linear", Abs[a # + b] & -> "Absolute Value"}, 
    ControlType -> PopupMenu},
  {{a, -2} -3, 3, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, -3,}, -5, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Here are the fixes.

1. Plot needs to wrapped in `Dynamic` so the plot will updated when the controls change.
2. The popup menu needs to be initialized just like the other controls.
3. The animator for parameter `b` needs to have it range specified correctly.

And, of course, it is mis-labelling to call `b` the `y-intercept` when `Abs` is plotted,