# Cannot use Plot inside Animate

Tags: plotting, animation

I am trying to write code to animate a resonance curve so that I can visualize changes in a parameter. However, even though my `Plot[]` plots values, my `Animate[Plot[]]` does not. I am unsure why.

```
resAmpEqn = a^2 == (f)^2 / (((res)^2 - w^2)^2 + 4 b^2 w^2);

Plot[resAmpEqn[[2]] /. {f -> 1, res -> 10, b -> 1}, {w, 0, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]

Animate[Plot[resAmpEqn[[2]] /. {f -> 1, res -> 10}, {w, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {b, 0.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Does anyone here know why?

Comment: Because the variable b in Animate is regarded only local. You have to give over the global b to the local b of Animate. Define `resAmpEqn[b_] = .....`  and use `Animate[Plot[resAmpEqn[b][[2]] /. {f -> 1, res -> 10}, {w, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {b, 0.5, 1.5}]
 `  or the dirty variant `Animate[Plot[
  resAmpEqn[[2]] /. {f -> 1, res -> 10, b -> bb}, {w, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {bb, 0.5, 1.5}] `

Comment: @Akku14 It would be great if you posted that as an answer, so the question won't appear to be unanswered even though you have answered it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple problem with Manipulate and Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25087/simple-problem-with-manipulate-and-plot) Notice that, as mentioned in Details and Options section of document of `Animate`, "`Animate` generates a `Manipulate` object containing an `Animator`. "

Comment: @Akku14
Very sorry for the delay. 

When I implement this, I get an error: "Tag Times in ((f^2)/(1.\w^2+(res^2-w^2)^2))[b_] is Protected"

Code I implemented:
`resAmpEqn[b_] = (f)^2/(((res)^2 - w^2)^2 + 4 b^2 w^2)


Animate[Plot[resAmpEqn[b][[2]] /. {f -> 1, res -> 10}, {w, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {b, 0.5, 1.5}]`