# Predefine plot for manipulate

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I have many messy plots that I want to plot in a grid. I'd like to keep things neat and tidy by redefining the plots elsewhere in the script.

I also want to plot them inside a manipulate function and vary parameters. However, while I can predefine

pi = Plot[fi[x],{x,a,b}]

and then do GraphicsGrid{{p1, p2},{p3, p4}} which keeps everything neat. Unfortunately, what does not work is :

myPlot = Plot[f[x,k],{x,a,b}];

manipulate[myPlot,{k,0,1}].

Ideally I'd like to define a bunch of plots then feed them into the manipulate ussimply using names.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us a complete code sample so we can test.

Comment: Anyway, if I have to guess, this is probably a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25087/1871